# How trivial is identifying a Tor user with JavaScript enabled/ 'allow scrips globally'?

Tags: javascript, tor

I was browsing using Tor, with Javascript enabled/ 'allow scripts globally'. I made an automated take-down request for something posted on a website, and the next day went back to check if the item was still there. It was, and irritated, i made the request again, and got an automated 'you have already made this request' type response on the website. Which is wierd because I was using a different Tor circuit than the previous day. So what is happening? Is it:

1. The website just acknowledging that 'somebody' already made the request?
2. The website recognising both requests were TOR users?
3. The website somehow identifying me as me despite TOR (presumably by some JS exploit)

If it's #3 then it must be pretty easy to identify TOR users who have JS enabled, no? Because it was just a random website not one inhabited by black-hat hackers or spooks. well, i assume not lol.

Comment: It *shouldn't* be trivial or possible, and would require an exploit. More-likely you had the same exit node, that exit node was already used, or the request was otherwise determined to be a duplicate.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I disagree. Session cookies are not disabled by Tor by default. I could set a session for the user. The session cookie is stored on the client side. So once they come back to the website I can associate their data with the session cookie.

Comment: @baconface I'm pretty sure Tor Browser dumps all that when it resets.

Comment: most likely either you left something behind that allows identification of you or the site left something behind to identify you. Options would be: same exit-node, a cookie, the fingerprint of your browser... AFAIK the tor-browser drops cookies after being closed, unless configured otherwise though

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara OP doesn't specify using TORbrowser or that the browser/pc was restarted so cookies is a likely thing

Comment: @wireghoul True, I guess I assumed the Tor browser from their changing of the NoScript setting. But if they did use Tor Browser, and used the "new identity" or otherwise reset (they did mention using a new circuit), cookies should have been erased.

Comment: It was using the TOR browser bundle. And I closed the browser inbetween uses. It's not to do with the exit node... checked that. What do you mean 'fingerprint of my browser' btw?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara : what do youmean 'or the request was otherwise determined to be a duplicate'?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by identified, if it said something like "request already submitted" after you submitted the second request, it might just be refusing duplicate reports.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara That's my option a). Though if memory serves, it said something more like 'you have already submitted the request'.

Comment: See https://panopticlick.eff.org/ for info about browser fingerprint. Visit it with the Tor browser

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to track visitors between sessions which are in no way hindered by TOR:

- HTTP cookies (yes, even .onion domains can use cookies like any other domain)
- Persistent storage with JavaScript in [Localstorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) or [IndexDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/)
- Persistent storage in plugins like Flash
- Browser Fingerprinting, i.e. looking at a combination of browser version, installed plugins, screen resolution, installed fonts and what other information you can get. Each of that by itself might not be enough to identify someone uniquely but can be when you look at the combination of all of it simultaneously.

If you want to avoid getting tracked, you might want to use the [TOR Browser](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en) provided by the torproject.org. It is a Firefox build with all of the above switched off as far as reasonably possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes for non persistent tracking purposes, websites encode a string that is propagated across each page of the site you surf through. If you have a browser history entry of such a page, clicking through it refreshes the history on the server side. This assumes you do not use no history settings on your client.

Answer (score 0):

Another method in addition to other answers: ETag can also be used in compliant browsers and doesn't need any plugin installed, nor will it pop up any questions to the user. TOR Browser is the way to go.